# Chartjs tooltip not showing depending on canvas size

Tags: chart.js, tooltip

I have a Chartjs line chart and the tooltips don't display when I use a canvas size of width="275" and height="80". With this example I noticed that the tooltips do display with the above canvas size but when I F12 to go into debug mode the tooltips stop displaying. If I use a canvas size of width="80" height="300" the problem disappears however I then have a large open area between my graph and the bottom of the page.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

My code executes when the page is loaded:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Graph</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="graph.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="buildChart()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" height="80" width="275">
    <!-- canvas id="myCanvas" height="80" width="300" -->
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function buildChart() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var bgColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)';
   Chart.scaleService.updateScaleDefaults('linear', {
       ticks: {
           min: 0
       }
   });
       myLabels = ["Label1","Label2","Label3","Label4","Label5","Label6","Label7","Label8","Label9","Label10"];
       myData = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9",""];
       myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
           type: 'line',
           data: {
                   labels: myLabels,
                 datasets: [{
                             backgroundColor: bgColor,
                             borderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                             borderWidth: 1,
                             label: 'My Test Data',
                             pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)',
                             pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)',
                             data: myData,
                             yAxisID: 'yAxis'
                           }]
                 },
        options: {
           scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                             id: 'yAxis',
                             type: 'linear',
                             position: 'left'
                            }]
                   }
                 }
        });
   myChart.update();
}
```

With this example I noticed that the tooltips do display but when I F12 to go into debug mode the tooltips stop displaying. While trying to resolve this I found that the problem seems to be related to the size of the canvas. I get the problem when I use a canvas size of height="80" width="275", if I use a canvas size of width="80" height="300" the problem disappears however I then have a large open area between my graph and the bottom of the page.

Comment: It's easier to debug problems if you present some code to debug. Please edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).